# Cocos2D: Best way to display text from font atlas?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Based on the use CCDirector makes of CCLabelAtlas, I tried the following:

```
scoreLabel = [[CCLabelAtlas alloc]  initWithString:@"0123456789" charMapFile:@"fps_images.png" itemWidth:8 itemHeight:12 startCharMap:'.'];
[scoreLabel setPosition:ccp(200, 200)];
[self addChild:scoreLabel];
```

I must be missing something as nothing displays. I'm using the basic .png that's supplied with Cocos2D.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: your code does work in my project with cocos2d 1.1. i increased the item width and height to 20 because it was cut off. did you try that? what cocos2d version do you have?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Cocos2D 2.0 - the bounding box shows like 80x12px which is good (10 characters wide)